# Linq wild card search mvc c#

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

i am trying to implement wild card search using linq in mvc application. but its not working.  please see my code, what i am missing here, everytime i click the search button it returns the same number of rows. means search is not working. please help

```
IEnumerable<ProductList> listProducts = null;
listProducts = IProductRep.GetAllProducts();

if (listProducts != null)
{               
    if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strName)) || (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strCategory))|| (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strBrand)))
    {
        listProducts = listProducts.Where(s => s.pro_name.StartsWith(strName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                        || s.CategoryName.StartsWith(strCategory,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                        || s.BrandName.StartsWith(strBrand, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)  );
    }
    ViewBag.totalRecords = listProducts.Count();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure strName, strCategori and strBrand have value?

Comment: I am trying to give ony one vlaue, means if i want to serach by brand then i am only giving value of the barnd and leave the other parameters empty.

Comment: Why do you assign `null` to `listProducts` and then immediately over write it with `IProductRep.GetAllProducts()`? Just assign that.

Comment: Are the unused filter variables `null` or empty? If `null`, EF 5 will ignore that part of the test, if `""`, EF 5 will send to SQL to code that will be true. What SQL is being generated?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that not all of `strName, strCategory, strBrand` has a value.
I assume that the vars that you did not assign are empty strings since if they were nulls you would get `ArgumentNullException` on:

```
s.field.StartsWith(null, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

If indeed the vars that were not been assigned with a value from the UI (or wherever it is getting assigned in) are an empty string, then `s.field.StartsWith(string.Empty, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` would always be true (cause every string starts with an empty string).
It means that you get all the records.

you can add the checks to the linq like so:

```
listProducts = listProducts
   .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(strName) && s.pro_name.StartsWith(strName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || 
...
```